# Porto 2.1.0 in Magento 2.1.2 minicart error

Tags: magento-2.1

Hello Guys I'm having problem with my magento 2.1.2 installation in the minicart section. I have porto 2.1.0 theme installed. The problem is the minicart and this is the error in the console.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Credits to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290563/knockout-js-uncaught-typeerror-unable-to-process-binding

**I have resolved it in three steps:**

1. Replace the `minicart.phtml` file from theme

   `app\design\frontend\Theme_namespace\Theme_module\Magento_Ch‌​eckout\templates\car‌​t`

   with core template `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart‌​`.
2. Replace `content.html` file from your theme

   `app\design\frontend\Theme_namespace\Theme_module\Magento_Checkout\web\template\minicart\content.html`

   with core template `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\content.html`
3. **Remove all pub/static/frontend**

   **remove var folder**

   **Run deploy static content** again `php magento setup:static-content:deploy`